Initializing new BorshCoder instance throws error (JS)
I am trying to decode a Solana transaction using anchor's BorshCoder. I have a seperate file with the IDL of which the content was copied 1 on 1 from here: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-idl/blob/master/raydium_amm/idl.json
When creating a new BorshCoder class like this:
const { BorshCoder } = require('@coral-xyz/anchor');
const IDL = require("./idl.json");

const borshCoder = new BorshCoder(IDL);

This error is thrown
throw new error_js_1.IdlError(`Type not found: ${field.name}`);
IdlError: Type not found: undefined

Is the IDL file incorrect? All IDL files I have tried so far didn't work one way or the other. So if this is the case could you provide me with a IDL json file that should work?

It seems that you use last (or one of the last) @coral-xyz/anchor sdk version. Since v0.30.0 IDL format has been changed. There is three ways to process provided idl json file:

Convert idl to new format with anchor.

anchor idl convert old_type.json -o new_type.json


Downgrade @coral-xyz/anchor for example to 0.29.0 in your project.
Just take it here converted.


Thanks for your time, that seems to work. I can initialize a new class instance now. Now when parsing following transaction: 65bW2oFfR1quofdPhQQac3z7yvRqq6PNDdCm9o4PzUEvyCJ4o5kGWCdJq4MeFqJppGrie5ajcjUniSYA5JeK9JT5 and grabbing the instruction with buffer <Buffer 09 00 84 d7 17 00 00 00 00 e0 f0 6e eb 0e 00 00 00> the sighash translates to 2WLCGzn3aFq which is not in the sighashlayouts thus the instruction is not decoding. Any thoughts?

@Joe , Try ready for use solution from repo where that json file is placed. There is RaydiumAmmCoder class. I didn't try but I think it should works fine.
